# Keeping score in XCode using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, label

So I want to keep a `Score` in an XCode project. But I want it to be like `0.01, 0.02...` until it gets to `1.00` and from `1` to continue like `1, 2, 3...`

My current code looks like this:

```
var Highscore = 0
var Score = 0

...

@IBAction func Action(sender: AnyObject) {

if (Score < 100) {

        Score++
        HighScoreLabel.text = "HighScore:\(Score)"

} else if (Score >= 100) {

        Score += 100
        HighScoreLabel.text = "HighScore:\(Score)"
```

I've already tried creating a  variables which divides Score, I've tried to make it a double (but I want `1, 2..` not `1.00, 2.00`), and I don't know what to do.
Please help me if you can, and feel free to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func action() {
    if (score < 100) {
        score += 1
        let someScore = score < 1 ? String(format: "%.2f", score) : String(format: "%.f", round(score))
        println("HighScore:\(someScore)")
    } else if (score >= 100) {
        score += 100
        let someScore = score < 1 ? String(format: "%.2f", score) : String(format: "%.0f", round(score))
        println("HighScore:\(someScore)")
    }
}
```

This should do it.

EDIT:
Used your code.

Comment: ^Could somebody explain this a little?

Comment: `formatter` is used to "format" the score if the score is smaller than `1`. If it's bigger, then round it up (or down), convert it to an `Int` and then pass it to your label as a `String`

Comment: Changed it a bit to make it look a bit better. Kept thinking there was something wrong, but it was your `score++` :p